# multi line comments in asterisk dial plan

Tags: asterisk

I knew single line comments in asterisk dial plan that is ";" e.g

```
 ;exten => s,1,Playback(project/eligibility_points_msc)
```

but what is used for multi line comments in dial plan?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Asterisk also allows us to create [block comments](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Block+Comments). A block comment is a comment that begins on one line, and continues for several lines. Block comments begin with the character sequence

```
;--
```

and continue across multiple lines until the character sequence

```
--;
```

is encountered. The block comment ends immediately after --; is encountered.

```
[section-name]
setting=true
;-- this is a block comment that begins on this line
and continues across multiple lines, until we
get to here --;
```

Comment: @shehzy then you'd better mark it as an answer to help others.

Comment: Btw, in AEL (\*.ael dialplan files) the multiline comment would be /* ... */, just like in C or JS.

Comment: And in extensions.lua it is: ```--[[``` (start) and ```]]``` (end)